# Geofencing in Grafana and influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb, geofencing

I have a lot of data coming in from the telemetry unit which I have plotted in grafana from influxdb. I would also like to have geofencing in the map. Any free plugin provided by grafana to help in geofencing?

Any other possible alternative to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Grafana alert in theory: configure alert conditions around coordinates. There will be some limitations, but it will have basic geofencing functionality.

Comment: Agreed thanks for replying. I was looking for some free hand drawing of geofencing on the map